# CSS - Expand Div on text overflow to the nearest word wrapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently in this situation

I have a container with two titles, h1 and h2

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Word1 Word2 Verylongword3</h1>
    <h2>Brief text</h2>
</div>
```

Titles are in vertical, one above the other using flexbox

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 350px;
}
```

I am asked to make in the most case possible the container staying 350px width but in case of very long word, the container has to expand himself in way that the text is wrapped more than you can but longest word (that was in text-overflowing) is all inside the div.

Practically, as rendering, text should be

> Word1 Word2
>
> Verylongword3

And not

> Word1 Word2 Verylongword3

If i fix the div width, i have text overflow. If i use flexbox or min-width text expands itself over all the line. Best solution is to do it in pure CSS but i may use javascript if its not theoretically possible in pure CSS.

I can't fix the width because Verylongword3 can be Word4 @ Word5 and in that case i should get

> Word1 Word2
>
> Word4 @
>
> Word5

As render

EDIT: in other words, container if needed (word larger than 350px width) must expand himself to contain the longest word but keeping the word wrapping

Comment: Sorry man, I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Can you explain it a little bit better?

Comment: I have a text in a container of fixed minimum width. Text actually wraps but a word can be longer than the div width (350px). In this case i have to expand the div to fit the longest word size but leaving the paragraph wrapping.

Comment: Whit javascript you can do something like that : $('h1').split("-").pop(); to get the last work of your title and preppend <br>

Comment: Yes i thought that as solution, but there are two problems. 1) Longest word can be in whatever point of the text, not necessarly last. 2) If i wrap all the lines i got Word1 <br> Word2 <br> LongestWord3 <br>  Word4 <br> Word5 as result that's not what i have to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who may it concern, the solution in javascript: detect text scroll size and enlarge it

```
$('.container').css("width", $('.container')[0].scrollWidth + "px");
```